# What is the meaning of $A := \left\{q q^{\top}:\|q\|=1, q \in E_{1}(X)\right\}?$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $X \in \mathcal{S}_m(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathcal{S}_m(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of (real) symmetric $m \times m$ matrices.

Let $E_{1}(X)$ denote the eigenspace associated with the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1(X)$ of $X$.

Note that $\lambda_1(X)$ can of course be a multiple eigenvalue and thus $E_{1}(X)$ can be more than one-dimensional.

---

**What is the meaning/ intuition of following set ?**

$$
A := \left\{q q^{\top}:\|q\|=1, q \in E_{1}(X)\right\}
$$

I understand that $A$ is a subset of the vector space of symmetric matrices of rank one.

If it wasn't for the $q \in E_{1}(X)$, I would say that $A$ is the unit circle in the vector space of symmetric matrices of rank one, as

\begin{align*}
\|qq^{\top}\|_{F} &= \sqrt{\langle qq^{\top}, qq^{\top} \rangle _{F}} \\
              &= \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}((qq^{\top})^{\top}(qq^{\top}))} \\
              &= \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(qq^{\top}qq^{\top})} \\
              &= \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(qq^{\top})} \\
              &= \sqrt{q_{1}^{2} + ... + q_{n}^{2}} \\
              &= \sqrt{1}=1 \, .
\end{align*}

But with the $q \in E_{1}(X)$ I am confused now.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $qq^T$ with $q$ a unit vector is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace generated by $q$ so this the set of all matrices that orthogonally project into the eigenspace associated with the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Many thanks for ypur answer. For my purpose it would be very beneficial if I could make a statement of the kind "$A$ is the unit circle in ...".

Can you think of anything like this?

For example, $\{q : \| q \| = 1, q \in E_{1}(X) \}$ is the unit circle in the (sub-) vector space $E_{1}(X)$ and $q \mapsto q^{\top}q$ is a ... operation such that ... "

Comment: @u49K3df2 The length of the vectors is $1$ to ensure that the projections are orthogonal. I don't see any relation between the unit circle and these matrices.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. There is something which still irritates me: If the eigenspace is more than 1-dimensional, why is $qq^{\top}$ still a projection matrix onto the eigenspace? Intuitivly I would expect that in this case I need a matrix whose columns form a normalized basis of the associated eigenspace...Is there some literature you can recommend to read up on this?